# Justify last line of UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

As far as I can see, `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` justifies all the lines of a section except the last one. So for example, if there aren't enough items to fill more than 1 line, the result is not justified.

[image]

What is the simplest way to either configure or subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` so that it also justifies the last line of a section?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout and overriding `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` to place all the items in the last line (except the first, which is already correct) where you want them, by changing the `frame` property of the item's UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes object.

Answer (score 11):

This is not really possible, unfortunately. It's just not designed that way, unfortunately.

One thing I can think of that might work though is to add an extra item into the data source, returned at the end, which has a cell that is 0 pixels tall and the width of the collection view. That will force the last row to be a single row with just that one item on it and then all rows above it will be justified.

Comment: Width of extra item should be `(width of collection view) - (left and right content inset) - (left and right section inset)`.

Comment: How do you tell the cell to be the size of the collectionview?