# Last item in UICollectionView not alligned - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have seen some questions similar to this one but none have really helped me. The last item in my collection view is always lower than the other items, as you can see in the image below:

[image: Last Item Unalligned]

If I increase the height of the `UICollectionView` then the last image alligns correctly but there is a huge gap between at the top and bottom of the `UICollectionView` as seen in the image below:

[image: Last Item Alligned]

The sizing of the cells are controlled by this code:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let image =  UIImage(data: imageArray[indexPath.row])

    var size = image?.size
        let height = size!.height
        let width = size!.width
        let imagewidth = (width / height) * 214



    return CGSize(width: imagewidth, height: 214)
}
```

From what I understand, this should be making the height of each of the images the same, meaning it doesn't matter what the height of the original image is.

I also have another collection view in which the last item is aligned correctly and is set up in the exact same way so I'm a bit confused. What do you think the problem is? I have read that this could be a bug, but is there anyway around it? I am still learning about Swift and programming in general so if you have any other tips for me, they would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I was having problems too with the last cell. I don't know if this is the same issue. If you are working with UICollectionViewFlowLayout then there's an, imo, strange behaviour with the last row/column. So if you try adding an additional cell to the collectionView with width=0 and height=collectionViewHeight, maybe that helps. -> see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13186435/1105464

Answer (score 0):

If there is a huge gap between at the top and bottom of the UICollectionView , you can solve the problem via setting `viewController's` `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` false.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //remove the blank of top and bottom in collectionView
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    }
```

Comment: Hey Rose. Thanks for your answer but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the solution here. That has worked for some other issues I have had but not this one.