# Adjust item spacing in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

I can easily set minimum item spacing to be 5 but I got another issue like this. Sometimes, spacing become larger. Instead of this behaviour, can I put 'aaaaaaaaa' in next line and the rest item still have spacing as 5.

[image]

Comment: you have to calculate textsize of that label and according to that label size you have to increase cell size

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to increase cell size. That margin is good.  Somehow, my question relate to this one but I don't know how to solve too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184883/justify-last-line-of-uicollectionview

Comment: I want to put white space after 'ASN' rather than having white space between 'Safety' , 'Incident' , etc.

Comment: I need to disable 'Justify' in my flow layout. How shall I do?

Comment: what is your default cell width ?

Comment: Default is 30 but I am using self-sizing technique with autolayout. Each cell size is now fully occupied by label. The one we see white space are due to spacing.

Comment: you can manage cell spacing into inspector pane or as per above my suggestion you have to calculate text size of that label and returning width of cell according to that label width

Comment: If you want fixed cell width, then your text will get truncated. Unless you want the **height** of the cell to increase and the label to become multiline? Right now all items should have spacing of 5 but number of items in each row will be different.

Comment: you can Use Flow layout for collectionView

Comment: Yes. I am using flowlayout (setting minimum spacing as 5 already) but it is setting minimum spacing. My case is different.